# PHPMailer envía los correos pero no se reciben

Tags: php, phpmailer, smtp, vps

He estado utilizando `PHPMailer` para enviar correos hasta hoy, que he cambiado el **VPS** que utilizaba. He configurado el servidor, instalado `composer`, `phpmailer` y `phpspreadsheet` en el nuevo servidor, y he probado que funcionase todo como antes.

`PHPSpreadsheet` funciona a la perfección, por lo que el `composer` está bien instalado, así como las 2 librerías. El problema que tengo es que en el servidor viejo, los correos se envían y llegan al destino, pero en el servidor nuevo todo parece indicar que se envían, pero nunca llegan.

Este es el código de prueba que estoy utilizando para enviar los emails.

```
<?php
// Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
// These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
require 'conexion.php';
use baseDeDatos\conexion as conexion;
// Load Composer's autoloader
require dirname(__FILE__)."/vendor/autoload.php";



$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->setFrom('info@weruleapp.es', 'weruleapp');
$mail->addAddress('weruleapp@gmail.com', 'weruleapp');
$mail->Subject  = 'PROBANDO PROBANDO';
$mail->Username  = 'info@weruleapp.es';                  // SMTP username
$mail->Password  = 'password';                    // SMTP password

$message = 'PROBANDO PEOPLE';

$mail->Body = $message;
$mail->Host = 'localhost';

$mail->isSMTP();

$mail->send();
echo "Email sent <br>";
```

Como digo, en el servidor antiguo funciona y en el nuevo no. El antiguo es un **VPS** de Aruba, el nuevo es un **VPS** de IONOS (1&1).

Este es el listado de puertos que tengo abiertos en el servidor nuevo:

```
Acción  IP permitida    Protocolo   Puerto(s)   Descripción         
Permitir    Todas   TCP     80      
Permitir    Todas   TCP     22      
Permitir    Todas   TCP     443         
Permitir    Todas   TCP     21      
Permitir    Todas   TCP     3306        
Permitir    Todas   TCP     10011       
Permitir    Todas   TCP     30033       
Permitir    Todas   TCP     25      
Permitir    Todas   TCP     465         
Permitir    Todas   TCP     587         
Permitir    Todas   TCP     143         
Permitir    Todas   UDP     9987
```

Este es un ejemplo de las trazas del debugger:

> 2019-12-22 23:50:35 Connection: opening to localhost:25, timeout=300, options=array()
>   2019-12-22 23:50:35 Connection: opened
>   2019-12-22 23:50:35 SMTP INBOUND: "220 localhost.localdomain ESMTP Postfix"
>   2019-12-22 23:50:35 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 localhost.localdomain ESMTP Postfix
>   2019-12-22 23:50:35 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO 82.223.204.222
>   2019-12-22 23:50:35 SMTP INBOUND: "250-localhost.localdomain"
>   2019-12-22 23:50:35 SMTP INBOUND: "250-PIPELINING"
>   2019-12-22 23:50:35 SMTP INBOUND: "250-SIZE 10240000"
>   2019-12-22 23:50:35 SMTP INBOUND: "250-VRFY"
>   2019-12-22 23:50:35 SMTP INBOUND: "250-ETRN"
>   2019-12-22 23:50:35 SMTP INBOUND: "250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES"
>   2019-12-22 23:50:35 SMTP INBOUND: "250-8BITMIME"
>   2019-12-22 23:50:35 SMTP INBOUND: "250 DSN"
>   2019-12-22 23:50:35 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-localhost.localdomain250-PIPELINING250-SIZE 10240000250-VRFY250-ETRN250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-8BITMIME250 DSN
>   2019-12-22 23:50:35 CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:
>   2019-12-22 23:50:35 SMTP INBOUND: "250 2.1.0 Ok"
>   2019-12-22 23:50:35 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.1.0 Ok
>   2019-12-22 23:50:35 CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:
>   2019-12-22 23:50:35 SMTP INBOUND: "250 2.1.5 Ok"
>   2019-12-22 23:50:35 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.1.5 Ok
>   2019-12-22 23:50:35 CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA
>   2019-12-22 23:50:35 SMTP INBOUND: "354 End data with ."
>   2019-12-22 23:50:35 SERVER -> CLIENT: 354 End data with .
>   2019-12-22 23:50:35 CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Sun, 22 Dec 2019 23:50:35 +0000
>   2019-12-22 23:50:35 CLIENT -> SERVER: To: =?UTF-8?Q?PABLO_GONZ=C3=81LEZ_DE_LA_IGLESIA?= 
>   2019-12-22 23:50:35 CLIENT -> SERVER: From: weruleapp 
>   2019-12-22 23:50:35 CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?Novedad:_Adaptaci=C3=B3n_a_m=C3=B3viles?=
>   2019-12-22 23:50:35 CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID: 
>   2019-12-22 23:50:35 CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 6.1.4 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
>   2019-12-22 23:50:35 CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0
>   2019-12-22 23:50:35 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
>   2019-12-22 23:50:35 CLIENT -> SERVER:
>   2019-12-22 23:50:35 CLIENT -> SERVER: PROBANDO
>   2019-12-22 23:50:35 CLIENT -> SERVER:
>   2019-12-22 23:50:35 CLIENT -> SERVER: .
>   2019-12-22 23:50:35 SMTP INBOUND: "250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 3253249DBE"
>   2019-12-22 23:50:35 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 3253249DBE
>   2019-12-22 23:50:35 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
>   2019-12-22 23:50:35 SMTP INBOUND: "221 2.0.0 Bye"
>   2019-12-22 23:50:35 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 Bye
>   2019-12-22 23:50:35 Connection: closed
>   Message has been sent

Comment: Revisa tus registros MX en **https://mxtoolbox.com/** y, de paso, también puedes ver si tu IP está en alguna lista negra.

Comment: Creo que no tienes todos los puertos abiertos, echale un ojo a la web de Ionos: https://www.ionos.es/ayuda/servidores-cloud/vserver-primeros-pasos/vps-primeros-pasos/

Comment: Era esto!! Aunque en mi política de firewall salga abierto, si no les llamas para que te lo abran sigue cerrado. Muchas gracias.

Comment: No creo que tenga que ver con registros MX el que no lleguen los correos adonde los mandes. En todo caso, si los mandas a un cliente gmail después de un tiempo será notificado si llegó o no. En otro caso si el correo lo mandas a un servidor al que tengas acceso, sí puedes saber (por lo regular en el mail.log) qué está pasando con el correo saliente y el correo entrante.